Switch end effector Moveit
I have a robot and two end effectors, a camera and a gripper. I should use before the camera and then the gripper, is it possible to switch from them while using moveit? I should be able to add the stl file of the camera with the collision associated with it, then delete it and add the one of the gripper.
How can I do it?
Thanks
I tried using the moveit setup assistant but i am not an expert so I was not able to do anything
